# How to get siblings of enum case to build custom picker?

Tags: swift, generics, swiftui

I'm trying to build a SwiftUI that accepts any enum case as its selection, then it will automatically render its siblings as options. Here's what I started with, but I'm having a hard time overcoming the generics:

```swift
enum Option: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable, Equatable {
    case abc
    case def
    case ghi
    var id: Self { self }
}

struct CustomPicker<Sources>: View where Sources: RawRepresentable & CaseIterable & Identifiable, Sources.AllCases: RandomAccessCollection, Sources.RawValue == String {
    @Binding var selection: Sources.AllCases.Element

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack(spacing: 8) {
                ForEach(Sources.allCases) { item in
                    Text(item.rawValue)
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to use it, I get a compile error: `Generic parameter 'Sources' could not be inferred`:

```swift
enum Fruit: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable, Equatable {
    case apple, banana, orange
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedFruit: Fruit = .apple // Error here

    var body: some View {
        CustomPicker(selection: $selectedFruit) // Error here
    }
}
```

How can I get the generics correct to be able to handle any String/RawRepresentable enum and build out its siblings automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not far from achieving the result you expect. Some comments:

- You don't need to require that `Sources` conform to `Identifiable`: it needs to be `Hashable` to work with `ForEach`, then force the `ForEach` to use `\.self` as the id. The raw value of the enum is of type `String` (you required it), using `\.self` will always work.
- `Fruit` is not `Identifiable` and it doesn't need to be.
- The main view is passing `Fruit` but the picker-view expects a type `Sources.AllCases.Element`: they don't match. Simply use `Sources` in your `@Binding`.
- Remember to update the value of the `@Binding`.

Here below you have a working example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedFruit: Fruit = .apple
    
    @State private var selectedCar = Car.ferrari

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomPicker(selection: $selectedFruit)
            
            CustomPicker(selection: $selectedCar)
            
            // Just for testing
            Text("Eating one \(selectedFruit.rawValue) in a \(selectedCar.rawValue)")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding()
        }
    }
}

// The Enum doesn't need to be Identifiable
enum Fruit: String, CaseIterable {
    case apple, banana, orange
}

enum Car: String, CaseIterable {
    case ferrari, porsche, jaguar, dacia
}

// Replace Identifiable with Hashable
struct CustomPicker<Sources>: View where Sources: RawRepresentable & CaseIterable & Hashable, Sources.AllCases: RandomAccessCollection, Sources.RawValue == String {
    
    @Binding var selection: Sources    // This is the right type

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack(spacing: 8) {
                
                // Force the id as the item itself
                ForEach(Sources.allCases, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text(item.rawValue)
                    
                        // Somehow you need to update the @Binding
                        .onTapGesture {
                            selection = item
                        }
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
    }
}
```